# Ionic 5 get item by ID from JSON

Tags: json, angular, sorting, ionic-framework

*Newbie question*

On a number of Ionic pages I need to get one item by ID from a central JSON file.

My JSON is like this:

```
 {
    "items": [
      {
      "id":"0",
      "link": "/cannaregio",
      "title": "Cannaregio",
      "area": "Cannaregio",
      "type": "place",
      "image": "./assets/imgs/attractions/canneregiosmall.jpg"
    },
    {
       "id":"1",
      "link": "/sanmarco",
      "title": "San Marco",
      "area": "San Marco",
      "type": "place",
      "image": "./assets/imgs/attractions/sanmarcosmall.jpg"
    },
    {
        "id":"2",
      "link": "/sanpolo",
      "title": "San Polo",
      "area": "San Polo",
      "type": "place",
      "image": "./assets/imgs/attractions/sanpolosmall2.jpg"
    },
    {
        "id":"3",
      "link": "/dorsoduro",
      "title": "Dorsoduro",
      "area": "Dorsoduro",
      "type": "place",
      "image": "./assets/imgs/attractions/dorsodurosmall.jpg"
    }
    ]
}
```

I need to get, the **title**, **area** and **type** from *one* of the IDs to display in the html page. Can anyone point me in the general direction of how I can achieve this? I have tried using various things but I'm just ending up very confused about how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

```
import * as data from "./items.json"

const item = data.items.find(item => item.id == 1);
```

item will be the second item of your array, the one with the id of "1".

Don't forget that your `tsconfig.json` should contain at least

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    [...]
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    [...]
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Edgar. How should the json be imported into the. ts file?

Comment: Your tsconfig.json should contain the entry `"resolveJsonModule": true,`. This should allow you to `import * as jsonString from "./items.json"`. But I guess then you don't have to parse the value of `jsonString`. It should just be an object after importing it. I updated the answer. I did not test it.

Comment: Thank you. I'll give it a go!